# Checking data-frame entries for duplicate records

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame `df` that I need to validate.  The `df` has several thousand records but looks something like:

```
   id         score  status
    1   0.204728295 current
    2   0.811946622 current
    3   0.255717294 current
    4   0.283495765 loan in
    4   0.355463338 loan out
    5   0.090287194 current
    6   0.195224702 current
    7   0.743183619 transfer in
    7   0.6677402   transfer out
    8   0.685349828 current
    9   0.664626162 current
    9   0.389797469 transfer in
    10  0.359471869 current
```

The validation is that there can only be a duplicate id in the df when:

- One of the duplicate status entries is 'transfer in' and the other entry with the same id had a status equal to 'transfer out' or
- one of the duplicate status entries is 'loan in' and the other entry with the same id had a status equal to 'loan out'

Any instances where the above does not hold would need to be captured for correction.

In the example id = 4 has a duplicate entry but the entries are valid as the status are 'loan in' and 'loan out'.  The same for id= 7 where the status's are 'transfer in' and 'transfer out'.  However id = 9 is invalid as the status's are 'current' and 'transfer in'

The output from the exercise would just be the records that fil validation.  In this case it would be:

```
   id         score  status
    9   0.664626162 current
    9   0.389797469 transfer in
```

I have figured out that I can look for duplicate records by using the following:

```
countdf = df.groupby('id').count()
result = df.loc[df['id'].isin(countdf[countdf['id'] > 1].index)]
```

but cannot figure out how then to check the duplicates ids against if they are mapped up to valid statuses.

Comment: Also, add expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way

```
In [2111]: conds = [['transfer in', 'transfer out'], ['loan in', 'loan out']]

In [2112]: df[df.groupby('id')['status'].transform(
                  lambda x:not any(all((x==c).any() for c in cond) 
                         for cond in conds) and len(x)>1)]
Out[2112]:
    id     score       status
10   9  0.664626      current
11   9  0.389797  transfer in
```

---

Details

```
In [2114]: df.groupby('id')['status'].transform(
              lambda x:not any(all((x==c).any() for c in cond) for cond in conds))
Out[2114]:
0      True
1      True
2      True
3     False
4     False
5      True
6      True
7     False
8     False
9      True
10     True
11     True
12     True
Name: status, dtype: bool

In [2115]: df.groupby('id')['status'].transform(
             lambda x:not any(all((x==c).any() for c in cond) for cond in conds) and len(x)>1)
Out[2115]:
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10     True
11     True
12    False
Name: status, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Elegant, but vulnerable to other examples of mistakes in the records. This will fail if there is a client id with a record of `"transfer in" "transfer out" "transfer in"` for example

Answer (score 0):

I have the following somewhat ugly solution. I reckon you'd want to look at @Zero 's answer and figure something out from there if you are looking for an elegant one.

```
df= df.set_index('id') #Only if it is not the index yet

index_dup = set(df.index[df.index.duplicated()])
df_dup = df.loc[index_dup]
drop = []
for bar in df_dup.status.groupby('id'):
    bar = bar[-1]
    if (bar == 'current').sum() > 1:
        continue
    if (bar == 'loan in').sum() != (bar == 'loan out').sum():
        continue
    if (bar == 'transfer in').sum() != (bar == 'transfer out').sum():
        continue
    index_dup.remove(bar.index[0])

df_dup = df_dup.loc[index_dup]
print(df_dup.sort_index()) #I changed some records to create more possible fails - They are caught

       score        status
id                        
2   0.811947       current
2   0.811947       current
7   0.743184   transfer in
7   0.743184  transfer out
7   0.667740   transfer in
9   0.664626       current
9   0.389797   transfer in
```